# SKU search from front end with Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, search, low-search

My client has asked to be able to search by Expresso Store SKU on the front end of their website. Is this even possible and if not what data would I need to manipulate in Store into a common custom entry field in order to make the SKU searchable?

We are currently using Low Search and the Low Search Store add-on to facilitate search.

```
{exp:low_search:results
    channel="book_library|products|products_postcards"
    store:price:min="0"
    query="{segment_2}"
    result_page="/shop/results"
    limit="20"
    paginate="both"
    status="not closed|Pending Review|Draft"
    }
```

Comment: The latest version of low search store has a parameter for sku search: store:sku (says it requires 3.4.0 of low search). I'm now laughing, because I think it was literally just added!

Comment: Yeah. Just added it after Nathan's request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you grab the latest release of [Low Search Store](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-search-store), you can use the `store:sku` parameter.

If you're using [Low Search v3.4.0+](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search), you can also use the parameter `store:search:sku`, which behaves like a [Field Search parameter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search).